# Uncool List Comprehension

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, list-comprehension, xlwings

Here's my function for finding the location of specific values on an Excel sheet.

```
from xlwings import Workbook, Range

workbook = Workbook('workbook location')

def get_data_locations():
    """ Find data locations from the first sheet in document. """
    first_sheet = Range('Sheet1', 'A1:Z200').value
    coordinates = []
    for x in range(len(first_sheet)):
        coordinate_pair = [[x + 1, y + 1] for y, z in enumerate(first_sheet[x]) if z == 'CO']
        if not coordinate_pair == []:
            coordinates.append(coordinate_pair)
    coordinates = [cp for [cp] in coordinates]
    print(coordinates)
```

As far as I can see, the code works as intended. However, for some reason it feels like I'm killing puppies here.

For example, adding nested list here seems redundant.

```
[x + 1, y + 1]
```

And requires another line of code just to remove this silliness.

```
coordinates = [cp for [cp] in coordinates]
```

I'm really fascinated by the beauty of Python and would appreciate any help on making my own code a little more charming.

Thanks!

---

**Cool list comprehension:**

```
def get_data_locations():
    """ Find data locations from the first sheet in document. """
    first_sheet = Range('Sheet1', 'A1:Z200').value
    coordinates = []
    for row_i, row in enumerate(first_sheet, 1):
        coordinates.extend([(row_i, col_i) for col_i, col in enumerate(row, 1) if col == 'CO'])
    return coordinates
```

Big thanks to Mike Müller who came up with this solution! I re-posted a slightly modified version of his code to bring out the value of BBrown's suggestion. Having meaningful names makes a world of difference for a beginner like me.

Comment: Is there only ever one cell in each row that has the value "CO"?

Comment: Can you post a self-contained example that actually runs; with imports and all. This would make it much easier to experiment with your approach.

Comment: @inspectorG4dget 'CO' can appear multiple times in one row.

Comment: @MikeMüller Added the code you asked for.

Comment: In that case, are you sure your code does what you want it to? that list-comp seems to suggest that "CO" appears only once per row

Comment: @inspectorG4dget Quite sure as I'm getting multiple coordinate pairs with the same row index.

Comment: Ok. The last suggestion in my answer should still do the trick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Python 2.7 and above this should work:

```
def get_data_locations():
    """ Find data locations from the first sheet in document. """
    first_sheet = Range('Sheet1', 'A1:Z200').value
    coordinates = []
    for x, row in enumerate(first_sheet, 1):
        coordinates.extend([[x, y] for y, z in enumerate(row, 1) if z == 'CO'])
    return coordinates
```

The method `extend()` adds the elements of a list (or an iterable) to another list. It is just like multiple calls to `append()`.

Starting from Python 2.7 `enumerate()` takes an optional start index.
So you don’t need the `+1` in `x +1` and `y + 1`.

The corresponding one-liner is not really a one-liner anymore:

```
def get_data_locations():
    """ Find data locations from the first sheet in document. """
    first_sheet = Range('Sheet1', 'A1:Z200').value
    coordinates = [[x, y] for x, row in enumerate(first_sheet, 1) 
                   for y, z in enumerate(row, 1) if z == 'CO']
    return coordinates
```

Answer (score 0):

My first thought is to do this:

```
def get_data_locations():
    """ Find data locations from the first sheet in document. """
    first_sheet = Range('Sheet1', 'A1:Z200').value
    coordinates = []
    for x,row in enumerate(first_sheet):
        coordinate_pair = [[x+1, y+1] for y,z in enumerate(row) if z == 'CO']
        if coordinate_pair:
            coordinates.append(coordinate_pair)
       coordinates = [cp for [cp] in coordinates]
    print(coordinates)
```

But it seems to me that "CO" appears in only one cell in each row of your excel sheet. If that is the case, then I would do this:

```
def get_data_locations():
    """ Find data locations from the first sheet in document. """
    first_sheet = Range('Sheet1', 'A1:Z200').value
    coordinates = []
    for x,row in enumerate(first_sheet):
        for row y,z in enumerate(row):
            if z != "CO": continue
            coordinates.append([x+1, y+1])
            break
    print(coordinates)
```

Of course, there's always a one-liner for nested for-loops:

```
def get_data_locations():
    """ Find data locations from the first sheet in document. """
    first_sheet = Range('Sheet1', 'A1:Z200').value
    coordinates = [list(itertools.chain.from_iterable([[x+1,y+1] for y,z in enumerate(row) if z=="CO"])) for x,row in enumerate(first_sheet)]
    print(coordinates)
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
for x in range(len(list_of_some_things)):
    do_something_with(list_of_some_things[x])
```

use the pattern

```
for thing in list_of_some_things:
    do_something(thing)
```

Use more a meaningful variable name than `x` and the latter pattern will read like English.